# How to Solve Unable to export or encryt the private key For Google App Signing

Tags: google-play-services, pem

I have an apk. I am trying to upload the new apk in publish console.As per the google rules we have to app signing. I have choose

export and upload a key from a Java keystore and i have download the pepk tool  and then i have copied the below command

java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=F:\Java\bin --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f15022017b00c64715022017b00c647f4ba4fe93fc8cef

Note: the encryption key is i have typed manually. For Security  purpose i  did not posted it.

When i run  the above command  in  command prompt. It asks for keystore password.  I have entered the keystore password. after it asks for  alias password. I did not set any alias password. If i  did not enter anything and then i click enter itsef. It says error.

Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key...

how to solve this error.

[image]

Comment: Well, the keystore file is not there (see the error message), maybe you have to create the keystore first?

Comment: Sorry i have posted wrong image. Now i have changed it. the keystore is file is there . It asks for alias password. I dont    what is meant by alias password.

Comment: What is meant by the alias password?

Comment: i have similar problem but though putting the correct key path

Comment: @RajeevKumar should i paste pepk path or keystore path

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I put all 4 files in one folder.

- foo.keystore
- private_key.pepk
- encrytion_public_key.pem
- pepk.jar

and use this command:

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=alias_name --output=private_key.pepk --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=encryption_public_key.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

It basically means you are using the wrong alias. Your alias when you were creating the Jks thingie was probably "upload" or something. Modify your code and replace foo with the actual Alias you used when creating the store.

Answer (score -4):

You need find out the alias name of your certificate from keystore file, you can use the command below.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

remember the

> keystore.jks file where it is actually located (path).

If you run the above command in the console. show you the output like that.
[image]

Now you have the alias name from your certificate and you can place it in your command (instead of using foo) and try again. I hope this will help you out.

Regards,